# How to open file of another application copied to my application's internal memory using root permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions, root

I am new to Android programming and I have noticed that when my application tries to open a file belonging to another app there is a "Permission denied" related error. i am aware that each app has its own internal memory not accessible by others however, the problem persists even after I copy/move the file to my app's data directory. (after acquiring root permissions)

I have already tried calling "chmod 777" on both the file and including directory with no result. Additionally, I tried to change the owner/group of the copied file to the UID of my application but the permission to open it still gets denied.

Here is an example of attempting to access a database of another app copied to my application's cache directory.

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

  String cp_db_command = "cp  " + main.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0).applicationInfo.dataDir + "/databases/db_name " + main.getCacheDir();

 //main is my Context

  os.writeBytes(cp_db_command + " \n");
  os.writeBytes("chown " + main.getApplicationInfo().uid + " " + main.getCacheDir()+ "/db_name" +" \n");

  os.writeBytes("exit\n");
  os.flush();

  p.waitFor();

  String url = main.getCacheDir()+ "/db_name";


   SQLiteDatabase mDataBase = null;



   mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(url, null);
```

The above code throws Exception with the following message android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database.
 The problem is not limited to databases but it also occurs with other files, opened with eg. FileInputStream.
I can, however, open files originally created by my application. I would like to know how Android recognizes that the file does not originally belong to my app even after altering owner, group or r,w,x permissions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `when my application tries to open a file belonging to another app` Where does such a file reside on the device when you consider it belonging to another app? Full path please.

Comment: It is created by the other app in /data/data/com.otherapp.package/databases/. I copy it to my dir (/data/data/com.My.Package/cache) using cp command which succeeds and then i try to open it.

Comment: Try to copy to yet another destination. Does this go ? For me this makes no sense. If you can write a file then you should be able to read it too.

Comment: Why dont you just self copy the file with a FileInputStream and a FileOutputStream?

Comment: Man you just write some command strings to that file. Nowhere are you copying. Did you ever check if amount of bytes of source and destination are equal?

Comment: @blackapps If I copy it to external storage, it is accessible in Android 8 real device but it remains inaccessible in Android 4.4.2 (emulator).

Comment: @blackapps the bytes that you see being written are written to the input stream of p process which has root permissions,not to the file. Process p calls the command as if it was a root shell and the file gets copied successfully. Sizes are equal.

Comment: Incredible. But then try to copy the file yourself.